# In macOS Sierra, How Configure AWS CLI to Use Python3.x Instead of the OS Default Python2.7?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, macos-sierra, aws-cli

Via macOS' Terminal, trying to install and configure **AWS CLI** on macOS Sierra 10.12.6 to use **Python 3.6.2** *instead* of macOS' default, Python 2.7.10.

Although I rigorously followed AWS' instructions (http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html), including configuring ./bash_profile thus:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.6.x
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

and double-checking via `**echo $PATH**`

```
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

When executing

```
$ aws --version
```

the result is always this:

```
aws-cli/1.10.60 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/16.7.0 botocore/1.4.50
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions as to **how to configure AWS CLI to ignore Python 2.7.10 and execute via Python 3.6.x.**

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I solved this problem via followings.

```
$ pip3 --version
  pip 18.1 from {....} (python 3.6)
$ export PATH=~/.local/bin:~/Library/Python/3.6/bin:$PATH 
$ pip3 install awscli --upgrade  # without --user
$ aws --version
  aws-cli/1.16.22 Python/3.6.5 Darwin/18.2.0 botocore/1.12.12
```

Comment: Thank you. Also, I would add
`export PATH=~/.local/bin:~/Library/Python/3.6/bin:$PATH`
to .bash_profile

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may have the `awscli` installed twice under different versions of Python, and the version installed on System Python is taking precedence.

Try running both of these commands and see if it shows up in both:

```
$ pip3 freeze | grep awscli
```

Then:

```
$ pip2 freeze | grep awscli
```

If it's listed in the latter, then run:

```
$ pip2 uninstall awscli
```

With a fresh install today, this is the output I get:

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.11.162 Python/3.6.2 Darwin/15.6.0 botocore/1.7.20
```

I'm not very familiar with how AWS recommends installing Python on macOS, but the most flexible way in my opinion is to install `pyenv` via `brew` then manage your Python versions through pyenv.  This allows you the flexibility of having multiple subversions of Python 2 and Python 3 installed simultaneously, as well as System Python.  I would recommend this approach here as well.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Instead of fixing it, I altered my path and installed with brew. It was seamless and the fastest solution.

```
$brew install awscli
```

Then,

```
$aws --version
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you install `awscli`? Did you use pip that comes with Python 3?

Check which pip you're using and use the one for Python 3 to install awscli.

Comment: Just as the manual says: pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user. But, aws --version returns aws-cli/1.10.60 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/16.7.0 botocore/1.4.50.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it work by doing this

```
export PATH=~/.local/bin:~/Library/Python/3.6/bin:$PATH 
pip3 install awscli
```